# Movie about an amulet and book of magic?

Tags: story-identification, magic

A girl gets an amulet/necklace then whole town become like zombies and try to kill her.

She's chased to a chapel where they break through the walls and doors. She finds a hatch and goes underground it's vast with lots of pillars.

A man turns evil through this book of magic and kills a guy by crushing glass and mixing it with ice & alcohol and makes him drink it. His goal may have been to open up a portal.

The movie came out sometime between 2009-2012. It was a 'B' movie type.

This is about all I can remember.

Comment: It would help us if you could edit the post with some more information about the book, see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info for help.  Is this a novel? A short story collection? Can you tell approximately when you read it and in what language?

Comment: I think it's a film she's looking for, but yeah, questions need to be answered.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like it could possibly be *The Dead Matter* from 2010? This was a direct-to-video release.

A girl called Gretchin is mourning her brother, she gets hold of an amulet that allows her to control the dead. Gretchin thinks that she could contact him with this, however she unwittingly creates a zombie army, they call the zombies **Post-Mortem Americans** in the film.

Two feuding vampires Vellich and Sebed turn up looking for the amulet. A bit later in the film McCallister a vampire hunter turns up to help Gretchin.

Tom Savini - Sex Machine from *Dusk till Dawn* plays the vampire Sebed.
Jason Carter - Marcus Cole from *Babylon 5* plays McCallister

Here is the [IMDb link](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt1055363/)

This picture might be the scene at the end you describe

[image: end scene?]

And here is the trailer for the film